# WS_EX_LAYERED windows does not move with respect to its parent window

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I have created a window which has WS_EX_LAYERED extended style.
After that I changed parent of this window as acall to SetParent.
But When I move parent window on desktop my window is not changing its position with respect to its parent.

```
int translevel = 50;  /* 0 - 255 */
      SetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,GetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE)|WS_EX_LAYERED );
      ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hWnd,RGB(0,0,0),translevel, 0x02);

      HWND hParent  = ::FindWindow(TEXT("TSSHELLWND"), NULL);

      ::SetParent(m_hWnd, hParent);
```

Note:- TSSHELLWND is the mstsc session window. I would like to make my window as a child of mstsc session window.

Is it not moving because I applied LAYESRED attribute on a child window????

Comment: Well, it is not a child window, only top-level windows can be layered windows.  Making it a parent of a system window, whatever tsshellwnd might be, seems pretty troublesome.  Surely it wasn't a child window of that window before.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `WS_EX_LAYERED` on child windows on pre-Windows8 systems. [The documentation says as much](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx):

> Windows 8: The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED only for top-level windows.